# What format to store recurring event patterns?

Tags: c#, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to represent “Recurring Events” in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579638/what-is-the-best-way-to-represent-recurring-events-in-database)

I'm planning an event calendar feature for my site, and want to allow users to enter recurring events by any combination of recurrence patterns (i.e. first Tues of every n months, every Tues/Wed each week, 13th every n months, etc...)

After trying to plan out the logic, my brain is starting to melt. How do you build an event in which it can follow nearly any combination of recurrence patterns? How do you query for an event on a specified day (assuming there are events, through some combination of it's recurrence pattern)?

I don't care about changing specific instances of a recurring event.

Comment: Isn't this question the same? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579638/what-is-the-best-way-to-represent-recurring-events-in-database

Answer (score 1):

Check out iCal specification - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar
overs all kinds of recurences (like every last Friday of each month).

Sample from [RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.5.3) :
Every 10 days, 5 occurrences:

```
   DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:19970902T090000
   RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=10;COUNT=5
```